# Selecting multiple rows with a sub-query

Tags: sql

The question asks "Display the names of all employees whose job title is the same as anyone in the sales dept" but

```
SELECT name, job 
FROM Employer WHERE job=(SELECT job FROM employer WHERE dept = sales);
```

does not work because the sub-query returns more than one value. How do I work around this?

Comment: I've removed the "homework" tag since it should no longer be used. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `in`

```
SELECT name, job 
    FROM Employer 
    WHERE job in (SELECT job FROM employer WHERE dept = sales);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Parado has the simplest solution. Keep in mind, however, that the `in` keyword is really just a `join`.  For example, your query is the same as:

```
SELECT e1.name, e1.job
FROM Employer e1
    JOIN Employer e2 on e1.job = e2.job
WHERE e2.dept = 'sales'
```